# Labeling a Plot with a Slash for Division Sign

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'm trying to label a 2D plot with something like $A/B$ rather than $\frac{A}{B}$.  I have tried:

`Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[A/B], y}]`

However, this leaves the $x$-axis as $\frac{A}{B}$.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `InputForm`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {InputForm[A/B], y}]
```

Or just string:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"A/B", y}]
```

You can also wrap these things in `Style` to get further:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {Style["A/B", 18, Bold, FontFamily -> "Georgia"], y}]
```

Comment: String works perfectly.  I actually needed something in the form of $A/B_C$, which didn't render correctly with InputForm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to get a display along the lines of the $\LaTeX$ command `\nicefrac` (with a shifted baseline for the numerator and denominator), you could do the following:

```
niceFrac[x_, y_] := 
 DisplayForm[
  RowBox[{AdjustmentBox[HoldForm[x], BoxBaselineShift -> -.5], "/", 
    AdjustmentBox[HoldForm[y], BoxBaselineShift -> .5]}]]
SetAttributes[niceFrac, HoldAll]

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {niceFrac[A, B], y}]
```

[image: nicefrac]

What I did in the function `niceFrac` is to give the first argument a nudge upward, and the second argument an equal downward push relative to the `/` symbol. This may be a useful compromise when you don't want to be completely one-dimensional but also don't want to waste too much space with the stacked fraction.

I added the `HoldAll` attribute only to allow you to typeset more complicated expressions that you don't want to evaluate (could be left out).