# Ugly fraction in a label

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, formatting, labeling, display

I'm having difficulties in displaying a proper fraction in a label.  Here's the 2D graphics which shows the problem :

```
PolarPlot[{
    LegendreP[5, Cos[theta]], 
    11/2 If[theta <= Pi,  1, -1]LegendreP[5, Cos[theta]]^2 Sin[theta]
    },
    {theta, 0, 2Pi},
    PlotStyle -> {
        Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Blue],
        Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Red]
        },
    PlotLabel -> Row[{
        Style[HoldForm[LegendreP[5, " cos \[Theta] "]], Blue, 16],
        "\n",
        Style[11/2 HoldForm[LegendreP[5, " cos \[Theta] "]^2 "sin \[Theta]"], Red, 16]
        }]
]
```

The label contains the fraction 11/2 which is badly formatted.  I would like to have the fraction displayed as a *small fraction* in front of **P_5(cos(theta))^2 sin(theta)**, *without the big parenthesis*.

Is that possible?

I am looking for a solution that works in Mathematica 7.

Comment: Wrap `11/2` in a `Style`.  e.g. `Style[Style[11/2, 10] HoldForm[
   LegendreP[5, " cos \[Theta] "]^2 "sin \[Theta]"], Red, 16]`

Comment: @Edmund, your suggestion works, but MMA still adds big parenthesis around the LegendreP.  How to prevent that ?

Comment: This issue bothered me too. There is no easy and satisfactory answer yet. For now I prefer to use the niceFrac function by Jens:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15204/labeling-a-plot-with-a-slash-for-division-sign

Answer (score 6):

Based on [@Mike's answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/36699/12), add `ScriptLevel -> 1` to `Style`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica uses the `ScriptLevel` value to determine when it should decrease the font size in equations.  The script level increases with each nested fraction/subscript/superscript.  I think that Mathematica switches to smaller fonts at a `ScriptLevel` of `1`.  In inline formulas (the ones you type with Ctrl-9 in text cells) the starting ScriptLevel is 1, thus fractions become small immediately.  Otherwise it is usually 0, so the outermost fractions are large (but things written within them become small).

---

However, the `ScriptLevel` is already `1` in `Column` by default, as opposed to `Row`.   Don't use `Row[{..., "\n", ...}]` if you mean a `Column`.  You may want to specify alignment using the second argument of [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column.html).

```
PolarPlot[{LegendreP[5, Cos[theta]], 
  11/2 If[theta <= Pi, 1, -1] LegendreP[5, Cos[theta]]^2 Sin[
    theta]}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Blue], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Red]}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Column[{Style[
     "\!\(\*FormBox[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(5\)](cos\\\ \
\[Theta])\),
TraditionalForm]\)", Blue, 16], 
    Style["\!\(\*FormBox[\(\*FractionBox[\(11\), \(2\)] \
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(5\)](cos\\\ \[Theta])\), \
\(2\)] sin\\\ \[Theta]\),
TraditionalForm]\)", Red, 16]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All this ugly `SuperscriptBox` stuff that you see above will format nicely in the front end if you paste it back:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I typed it like this:

- type `"x"`
- select the `x` and press Control-Shift-T to convert to TraditionalForm
- position the cursor next to the x, then type the formula as you normally would

Personally I prefer to type formulae directly into a single string rather than try to mix strings with HoldForm in a complicated way.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**  According to the OP's comment, he is looking for a solution that works in Mathematica 7.  MaTeX requires Mathematica 10.  I am leaving this answer here in case others find it useful, but note that it does not solve the OP's problem.

---

If you're fussy about formula formatting, you'll be better off using [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html).

```
MaTeX["\\frac{11}{2} P_5(\\cos \\theta)^2 \\sin\\theta", 
 "DisplayStyle" -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I made MaTeX precisely because people I worked with were fussy about formatting.

---

Load package:

```
<<MaTeX`
```

Add the `color` package to the preamble and change to CM Bright sans-serif fonts:

```
SetOptions[MaTeX, 
 "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{cmbright}", 
   "\\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}", "\\usepackage{color}"}]

PolarPlot[{LegendreP[5, Cos[theta]], 
  11/2 If[theta <= Pi, 1, -1] LegendreP[5, Cos[theta]]^2 Sin[
    theta]}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Blue], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Red]}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  MaTeX["{\\color{blue}P_5(\\cos\\theta)},\;\; \
{\\color{red}\\frac{11}{2} P_5(\\cos \\theta)^2 \\sin\\theta}", 
   "DisplayStyle" -> False, FontSize -> 16]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't know MaTeX (that's in Mathematica ?).  The 11/2 fraction displayed above is what I want in MMA labels.  However, your code doesn't appear to work in my old version 7.

Comment: @Cham You have to click the link to see what it is, but it does not work with Mathematica 7.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't totally happy with this.  Even in the LaTeX code by Szabolcs, the fraction is larger than the `P` right next to it.  But this gives close to the same thing as his, but without an external package

```
PolarPlot[{
      LegendreP[5, Cos[theta]], 
      11/2 If[theta <= Pi,  1, -1] LegendreP[5, Cos[theta]]^2 Sin[
    theta]
      },
     {theta, 0, 2 Pi},
     PlotStyle -> {
           Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Blue],
           Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Red]
           },
     PlotLabel -> Row[{

    Style[HoldForm[LegendreP[5, " cos \[Theta] "]], Blue, 16],
            "\n",

    Row[Style[#1, Red, #2] & @@@ {{11/2, 
        8} , {HoldForm[
         LegendreP[5, " cos \[Theta] "]^2 "sin \[Theta]"], 16}}]
            }]
 ]
```

[image]